# Web view and accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Is it possible to click (with AccessibilityService) specific buttons that are placed inside Webview? E.g some application A has a webview inside MainActivity. After activity started web content is loaded in webview. Loaded web page contains button with text "Chat". Can I click this button with Accessibility Service? I know I can perform click on Android native widgets (android.widget.Button, TextView etc) but I don't know how to perform click on the button that displayed on web page inside web view. Please help :)